# postfix 2.96 smtpd_relay_restrictions vs smtpd_reciepient_restrictions

Tags: server, email, postfix

we are setting up `postfix.main.cf` and if use

```
smtpd_**relay**_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
```

we get the warning of

```
unused paramters
```

when we 'service postfix restart

if we comment out that line and instead use

```
smtpd_**recipient**_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
```

we dont get warning however this command is only supposed to work on much earlier versions of postfix (prior to 2.1). and also on the early version we maybe should use `check_relay_domains` instead of `reject_unauth_destination`??? maybe?

The only thing we can think of that somewhere other than `postfix.main.cf` there is the line s`mtpd_recipient_restrictions` but we cannot find this.

help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing version numbers.

If you run this command, you’ll see that you’re not running Version 2.10, which is the first version that supports **smtpd_relay_restrictions**.

```
postconf mail_version
```

Ubuntu precise (12.04) has postfix version 2.9.6, which supports what you want to do with the **smtpd_recipient_restrictions** parameter.

See http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions